# Finding the median value of a random array

Tags: java, median

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding the median value of an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691940/finding-the-median-value-of-an-array)
>   [How to calculate mean, median, mode and range from a set of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191687/how-to-calculate-mean-median-mode-and-range-from-a-set-of-numbers)
>   [Combine QuickSort and Median selection algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10609602/combine-quicksort-and-median-selection-algorithm)

How can I find the median values of a randomly generated array?

For Example: It would give me an array like 88,23,93,65,22,43 . 
             The code I'm using finds the middle number but it's not sorted.

Here is the code I'm using so far:

```
double Median()
{
    int Middle = TheArrayAssingment.length / 2;
       if (TheArrayAssingment.length%2 == 1)
        {
           return TheArrayAssingment[Middle];
        }
    else {
        return (TheArrayAssingment[Middle-1] + TheArrayAssingment[Middle]) / 2.0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Dont forget to post your code.

Comment: why not just sort the array first then?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: This question has been asked [before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191687/how-to-calculate-mean-median-mode-and-range-from-a-set-of-numbers)

Comment: Duplicate [Finding the median value of an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3691940/1048330)

Comment: If you want fastest asymptotic behaviour, [median of medians](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1790360/1468366) would be the way to go. But that is pretty advanced stuff. By the way, if this is [homework](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/188688), please tag it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good but *it assumes the array is sorted.* Just sort it:

```
Arrays.sort(TheArrayAssignment);
```